# template is not being populated with the correct data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs, and I do not know why the templates do not populate with the data from the controllers.js file. All paths in the script tags are correct. Any help? This is angular 1, by the way.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
 //Create a model, basically, the data
 $scope.author = {
  'name': 'Some author'
  'title': 'Author'
  'company': 'lynda.com'
 }
 //After creating the data (author), we need to use it in the view (html)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Angular Demo</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <input type="text" ng-model="name">
 <h2>Welcome {{name}}</h2>
 
 
 <div ng-controller="MyController">
  <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
  <p>{{author.title + ',' + author.company}}</p>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this code most certainly generated some console errors, which should give you some idea of where the problem is at.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your actual code, then the issue is that there were missing commas in the `$scope.author` object.

This was clear by the output in the Developer's Console.  Learn to use your browser's developer console - it will be an absolutely essential tool for developing in Angular.

Here is your code - with the commas added - working.  Click **Run** for the snippet.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
 //Create a model, basically, the data
 $scope.author = {
  'name': 'Some author',
        // added comma here ---------^
  'title': 'Author',
        // and another here -----^
  'company': 'lynda.com'
 }
 //After creating the data (author), we need to use it in the view (html)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Angular Demo</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <input type="text" ng-model="name">
 <h2>Welcome {{name}}</h2>
 
 
 <div ng-controller="MyController">
  <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
  <p>{{author.title + ',' + author.company}}</p>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```